# Should Java JDBC Select statements always be in a Try-Catch block?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

Is it good practice to put all Java JDBC Select statements in a try-catch block ? Currently I write most of my code without it. However, I do try-catch for insert/update/delete.

Note: Currently using Sprint Boot.

```
String sqlQuery = "Select productId, productName, productStartDate from dbo.product where productId = 5"

public getProductData() {
    ....
    List<Product> productList =  namedJdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new ProductMapper());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this question is tagged with `spring-boot` and you are using JdbcTemplate, I'm giving you a Spring-specific answer.

One of the points of Spring is to avoid boilerplate from developers. If you find yourself adding things repetitively, like putting try-catch blocks around code executing DML, that's cause for suspecting you're not doing something right. Adding your own try-catches in code using Spring isn't always wrong, but it usually is.

In the Spring reference doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc there is a table showing what is the developer's responsibility and what is Spring's responsibility. Processing exceptions, handling the transactions, and closing jdbc resources are all shown as being Spring's responsibility.

SpringJdbc takes care of a lot of things for you. It handles closing JDBC resources and returning connections to their pool, and converts exceptions from SQLException to a hierarchy of unchecked DataAccessExceptions. In Spring unchecked exceptions thrown from a method wrapped in a transactional proxy cause the transaction to get rolled back. If you do your own try-catch logic you can prevent rollback from occurring when it needs to, if you catch the exception and the proxy never sees it. Adding try-catch logic can cause problems if you don't understand what Spring is doing.

Exceptions do need to be caught somewhere. In a Spring web application, you can set up an exception handler that catches anything thrown from the controller layer, so that you can log it. That way the action in progress gets broken off cleanly, the current transaction rolls back, and the exception gets handled in a consistent way. If you have other entry points, such as reading messages from a queue, those will need their own exception handler.

Exceptions are thrown in order to escape the current context, which isn't able to deal with the problem, and relocate control to somewhere safe. For most exceptions coming from JDBC, they aren't anything you can fix, you just want to let it be thrown, let the current transaction rollback, then let the central exception handler catch and log it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you're working with raw JDBC API, you should always use [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Yes, you'll just have to wrap the code with try-catch block at some point, though it's a good practice to catch exceptions just right away or at the point where it's logically suits. In case of SQL queries, you actually *should* wrap all of them into some `Service` class that will give you an access to modify your database objects without running through JDBC API every time. For example:

```
public class UserService {
    private static final String CREATE_USER_SQL = "...";
    private final Connection jdbcConnection;

    public @Nullable User createUser(final String name) {
        try (final PreparedStatement stmt = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(CREATE_USER_SQL)) {
            jdbcConnection.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt.setString(1, name);
            stmt.executeQuery();
            jdbcConnection.commit();
            return new User(name);
        } catch (final SQLException createException) {
            System.out.printf("User CREATE failed: %s\n", createException.getMessage());
            try {
                jdbcConnection.rollback();
            } catch (final SQLException rollbackException) {
                System.out.printf("Rollback failed: %s\n", rollbackException.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This solves two problems right away:

1. You won't need to put boilerplate JDBC code everywhere;
2. It will log any JDBC errors right away, so you won't need to go through a complex debugging process.

Comment: The OP is using Spring Boot, hence the `namedJdbcTemplate`. This allows you to use meaningful parameter names instead of error-prone parameter numbers.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, I didn't even notice, thanks :D

Comment: Also if OP is using spring boot and jdbcTemplate, exceptions will get converted to DataAccessExceptions, and catching exceptions within service will interfere with transactions.

Comment: btw, I am using Spring boot, not sure if that changes the answer

Answer (score 1):

Brief explanation:

1. First of all any resource involving I/O access (database access is I/O access) must always be closed or it will cause a **memory leak**.
2. Secondly, it is better to rely on `try-with-resources` to close any resource as having to call the `.close()` method manually is always exposed to the risk of not being effectively executed at runtime due to a potential `Exception`/`RuntimeException`/`Error` getting thrown beforehand; even closing the resource in a `finally` method is not preferable as such block executes at a different phase compared to the `try-with-resources` - auto closure of try-with-resources happens at the end of the `try` block, while `finally` executes at the end of all `try`/`catch` block - , in addition to the basic problem that it is not a secure solution as a `throw` might happen even inside the `finally` block, preventing it from completing correctly.

This said, you always need to close:

1. `Statement`/`PreparedStatement`/`CallableStatement`
2. any `ResultSet`
3. the whole `Connection` when you don't need DB access anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try-catch for DB Layer code is important if you're querying with JDBC.

Think about, **what if the connection broke? Or what if Database crashed ? Or some other unfortunate scenario comes up.**

For these things, I will recommend you to always keep the DB layer code within try-catch.

It's also recommended for you to have some **fallback mechanism** in-case of the above events.

Comment: btw, I am using Spring boot, not sure if that changes the answer

Comment: Answer, won't change. You're using spring-boot along with JdbcTemplate.

Comment: ok, yeah, this answer was saying something else, maybe you can address it, thanks again, https://stackoverflow.com/a/73420824/15435022

Answer (score 0):

You should always handle it with try cactch.

Why: For example you started a connection to db then some exception happened, if you don't rollback your transaction it stay on db and performance will be decreased, and memory leak will be happen.

Imagine, if your connection limit is 100 and 100 exception throwed after transaction started and you didn't rollback it your system will be locked because of you can't create any new connection to your database.

But if you want an alternative for "try catch finally" you can use like this:

```
EmUtil.consEm(em -> {
    System.out.println(em.createNativeQuery("select * from temp").getResultList().size());
});
```

Source code:

```
public final class EmUtil {

    interface EmCons {
        public void cons(EntityManager em);
    }

    public static void consEm(EmCons t) {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEmf().createEntityManager();
            t.cons(em);
        } finally {
            if (em != null && em.getTransaction().isActive())
                em.getTransaction().rollback();
            if (em != null && em.isOpen())
                em.close();
        }
    }

    private static EntityManagerFactory getEmf() {
        //TODO
    }
   
}
```

Comment: btw, I am using Spring boot, not sure if that changes the answer

Answer (score 0):

Spring translates those exceptions as `DataAccessException` (for more detail [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html)). It will be good to catch those exceptions and you can rollback with `@Transactional`.